# Does IE/Edge run Javascript when printing?

Tags: javascript, printing-web-page

I have a web page that has some client-side javascript that's fired via an onload() event handler in the body tag.  This works fine when viewing the page in a browser.  However, when printing the page via window.print(), the script doesn't run, and the fields don't display on the printed page in IE and Edge.  Chrome and Firefox work fine, though.  Has anyone seen anything like this?  I tried searching via Google and Bing, and even here, but the only results I could find were people having issues printing, and not with whether or not JavaScript runs when the page is printed.

Comment: can you add some example script/web page?

Comment: try to execute your code on `onbeforeprint` event : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint